# Displaying all values inside object inside array in mongodb using php

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

This is the structure for my MongoDB documents

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa02da4f6c9bf20da58017b"),
    "Name" : "HP Envy",
    "Model" : "m6 convertible x360",
    "Cost" : 1350,
    "Description" : "Sleek and slim laptop designed perfectly for business p
urposes",
    "Keywords" : [
            "Touchscreen",
            "Rotation",
            "x360",
            "Slim",
            "HP"
    ],
    "Reviews" : [
            {
                    "User" : "User 1",
                    "Comment" : "Great Laptop",
                    "Rating" : 4.5
            },
            {
                    "User" : "User 2",
                    "Comment" : "Great Laptop",
                    "Rating" : 4.5
            }
    ]
}
```

I want to access the data contained inside "Reviews" using php. I can access it normal using

```
$coll=$db->Product;
$cursor = $coll->find();
```

and then echo using a foreach to display in a tabular format. But i only know how to access the ID, name etc. How can i access the Reviews inside the object arrays? i tried something like this:

```
$test=$coll->find(array( 'Reviews.User' => 'User 1' ));
```

when i try to echo it it gives me an error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class MongoCursor could not be converted to string
I'm lost please help.. I apologize if i repeated the question but i couldn't find it anywhere else

Comment: Note that you're trying to echo out a `MongoCursor` which is a type of iterator. It's not even an array. You can call `$document_array = iterator_to_array($cursor)` to return an array, or you can do `foreach($cursor as $document) { . . . }` to perform operations on each individual document.

Comment: `foreach ($cursor as $cust){
   echo "<tr><td>";
   echo $cust['_id'];
   echo "</td>";
   echo "<td>";
   echo $cust['Name'];
   echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
   echo $cust['Model'];
   echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
   echo $cust['Cost'];
   echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
   echo $cust['Description'];
   echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
   echo implode(", ",$cust['Keywords']); // used to display an array as a 
    string split by commas`

Im already using this to access the values but i don't know how to access reviews :/

Comment: `$cust['Reviews']` will return the array of reviews. You could, for example, do `foreach($cust['Reviews'] as $review) { . . . }` where `$review` will then be an associative array containing the keys "User", "Comment", and "Rating".

Comment: Oh thank you finally it worked, Can I use the same way to change values ?

Comment: Important to note is that if you have something like `foreach($array_or_iterator as $element) {}`, the variable `$element` will be a copy of the array element, not a reference, so any changes you make to that element will not be saved. If you want to modify values, you need to do something like `$document_array = iterator_to_array($cursor); foreach($document_array as &$document) { /* modify $document here */ }`. The key here is the `&` operator, which tells `foreach()` to treat `$document` as a reference. Be sure to be mindful of how PHP generates these values or you'll get tripped up! :)